# How to open link on new window without calling onclick

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, tabs

I have HTML code as follows:

```
 <a href="#" onclick="reloadPage()">Text</a>
```

When user clicks by "Left mouse button" on the link, then reloadPage() should be called.

But when user clicks using "Ctrl + click" or "middle button" on the link then I want to open a new window without reloadPage().

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can refference [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dieuhd/d7pp3bhf/). Its my code

```
<a href="#" id="test" onclick="reloadPage(event)">Click Me</a>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

$(document).keydown(function(event){
    if(event.which==17)
        cntrlIsPressed = true;
});

$(document).keyup(function(){
    cntrlIsPressed = false;
});
});
var cntrlIsPressed = false;


function reloadPage(mouseButton,event)
{
        //event.preventDefault();
    if( event.which == 2 ) {
        //todo something
      //window.open($("#test").attr("href"));
      alert("middle button"); 
      return false;
    }
    if(cntrlIsPressed)
    {
         //window.open($("#test").attr("href"));
        // ctrl + click 
        return false;
    }
    //todo something
    window.location.href = $("#test").attr("href");
    return true;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! But I don't sure that have only 2 ways I have listed to open new window.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply set the `href` attribute on the `a` tag to the current page url, this way when a user clicks it will open the same page (reload) and if he middle clicks it will open the same page in a new tab.

If you want to use that on multiple pages then you can set the `href` in javascript to the current page url like this

```
document.getElementById('myId').href = location.href
```

Comment: Thank for your help, your way is very interesting.
But the function reloadPage() is an examples for call to do something.

Comment: what kind of logic are you doing? can it be done after the page reloads?

Comment: When we click by left mouse button then onclick should be called.
But when we using any action to open on new window then onclick shouldn't be called.

Comment: I don't think there is a reliable way to detect if the user clicked or clicked open in new tab. However, you can check if a page was opened in a new tab AFTER it opens from `window.history`

Comment: Thank you! I was expecting something like event.open_url_blank. Then I'll make sure to open a new window without call onclick.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach (html):

```
<a href="#" id="mylink">Text</a>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function () {
        $("#mylink").click(function (event) {
            if ((event.button == 0 && event.ctrlKey) || event.button == 1) {
                event.preventDefault();
                window.open("http://www.google.com");
            }
            else
                if (event.button == 0)
                    window.location.reload();                                
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have two options for you.Pure javascript and with the use of jquery.

Here's the full code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#jqueryStyle').mousedown(function(e){
            //3 is right click
            if(e.which == 3){
               window.open("http://www.w3schools.com");
            //1 is for click
            }else if(e.which == 1){
                reloadPage();
            }
        });
    });

    function reloadPage(){
       location.reload();
    }

    function onMouseDown(e,obj){
        e = e || window.event;
        //3 is for right click
        if(e.which == 3){
            window.open("http://www.w3schools.com");
        //1 is for click
        }else if(e.which == 1){
            reloadPage();
        }
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

     <a href="#" id="jqueryStyle">JQuery Code</a ><br/>
     <a href="#" onmousedown="onMouseDown(event,this)">Pure Javascript Code</a >
</body>
</html>
```

Hope that helps.